# php（eclipse上）で、githubから落としてきたファイルのクラスの呼び出し方法は？

Tags: php, eclipse

php初心者です。
eclipseを導入して、githubからファイルを落としてきてプロジェクトとしてインポートしました。
そのファイルのクラスを呼び出したいのですが、どういうやり方が正しいのでしょうか？（他プロジェクトから普通に呼び出せるものなのでしょうか？）
やりたいことは下記の図です[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

ご教示いただければ幸いです

追記：図2[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 利用したいライブラリはhttps://github.com/ekinhbayar/BrillTaggerですかね？

Comment: はい、そうです。現在、composerを使って図2（上の図をご覧ください）の場所にインストールして、ライブラリのクラスを呼び出して動作するところまではいきました。のですが、eclipse上で「型が解決できない」エラーが起きてしまいます。
インクルードパスとビルドパスを通す？と解決できるのでしょうか？

Comment: また、eclipse上でも、エラーが出ている箇所を、デバッグして値を追うこともできているので、問題がないと言えば問題ないかもしれません。

Comment: ではComposerを利用して解決したということですね。質問自体変わったしまっているのでこちらの質問は自己回答をしてもらって、新たに質問を作成してください。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composerを導入してライブラリをインストールことにより、自己解決したので終了します
（コメント参照）